# Firebase Phone Authentication with invisible reCAPTCHA challenge appears

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is working as expected but the only problem I need to fix is I use invisible reCAPTCHA as mentioned in [firebase phone auth documentaion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#use-invisible-recaptcha).

This is how I setup the code:

```
export const recaptchaVerifier = (): RecaptchaVerifier => {
  return new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, "recaptcha-container", {
    size: "invisible",
  });
};

export const sendOtp = async ({
  phone,
  verifier,
}: SendOtp): Promise<ConfirmationResult | null> => {
  // TODO: will change from fakePhoneNumber to phone
  const existed: boolean = fakePhoneNumbers.some(
    (fake) => fake.phoneNumber === phone
  );

  if (!existed) return null;

  return await signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phone, verifier); 
};
```

Usage:

```
const verifier = recaptchaVerifier();
const confirmationResult = await sendOtp({ phone, verifier });
```

The only problem is that the challenge sometimes appears and disappear. I don't know what I am missing from the configuration.

[image]

The challenge should disappear since I use invisible reCAPTCHA